# I want to delete the first character of a string

Tags: java, android, char

I have very very silly question but it is taking me a long time and I really don't know what the problem is. Take a look to my code please:

```
String PT = myedittext.getText().toString();
int len = PT.length();
char chars[] = PT.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
chars[i] = chars[i++];
```

As you can see, I want to delete the first character but it is not working and after this code my array is the same before.

I'm going crazy. What is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs here:

```
chars[i] = chars[i++];
```

This is the same as:

```
chars[i] = chars[i];
i = i + 1;
```

For removing the first character you should use substring:

```
 PT.substring(1)
```

Comment: yes it does, because you increase the index immediately and length is only 4, you should use substring to fix your problem, will be the easiest way

Answer (score 5):

If you want to get rid of first character, just use `substring()`:

```
String newString = PT.substring(1);
```

Comment: yeah. `PT.substring(1)` will do it.

Answer (score 1):

change this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
chars[i] = chars[i++];
```

to this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < len-1; i++)
chars[i] = chars[i+1];
```

the result string will be:

```
Arrays.toString(chars);
```

also if you don't need the char array and now that you know the problem of your code `substring` would be a better alternative.

Comment: Thanks a lot. it is working but we should add this line too    b = b.substring(0, b.length() - 1);

Comment: you're welcome:) and yes the last line that you mentioned is needed too

Comment: Im not sure why u accepted this answer? This code didnt work: If you try to use the word 'Hello' it will return 'elloo'. I dont think that is what you want?

This happens because you have an array with length of 5 and your new word only have a length of 4

Just saw ur comment with `b = b.substring(0, b.length() - 1);` But then u can use substring directly without using an char array and a loop because this will take a lot more performance

Comment: oh my question is not the whole story. i have a few conditions that depend on the first character that is why i have to convert the string to char. but you are right i can use this String newString = PT.substring(1); after my condition